# Why do I have to restart the Next.js dev server to see changes?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have a Next.js project that has been a real delight to work on until recently when changes stopped showing up in the browser. Normally the browser hot reloads, but now even hitting refresh won't show changes to the code—I have to shut down the dev server and run `npm run dev` again to get the changes to show up. This doesn't happen in all my Next.js projects—just one of them.

I've tried deleting the `.next/` directory, but that didn't fix the problem. Any other ideas of where I could look to get this back to normal?

- Next 12.1.0
- Node 14.18.1
- macOS 12.3

Comment: Are you making changes to your back-end node server or the front-end? Generally, only the front-end changes will automatically reload. Changes made to the server show on server restart.

Comment: I'm just making changes to the front-end—updating text and JSX tags and whatnot.

Comment: Did you fix this in the end?

Comment: Nope, I never figured out what was going on. I did narrow the problem down to a single component. Like: changes to this one component won't show up in the browser until restarting the server, but everything else works as expected. Shrug!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my case it was case sensitivity.

It turned out I renamed one of my components where the new name only had a letter changed from uppercase  to lowercase (e.g. `MyCOmponent.tsx` -> `MyComponent.tsx`).

I made all the changes everywhere but missed one, the import path of the component in one of the pages.
I  had: `import MyComponet from '../../MyCOmponent.tsx'`

Everything still worked when restarting the server, but hot reload or even browser refresh wouldn't, same as OP.  Fixing the typo  fixed everything.

Comment: Wow, such an easy thing to miss! I had imported as `Tracklist` when it should have been `TrackList`. This solved my issue—thank you!

Comment: For anyone who thinks they are having this issue but is having a difficult time tracking down what file name or import is causing it: try deploying to vercel and it will fail to deploy because of this issue as well, and tell you the bad import. Might be better ways to track this down but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I created a new file with a different name and copied all the content which was inside the file that did not show the changes. Then it started showing the changes in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using next.js. Simply use

> **npm run dev**

and make sure you have
`"scripts":{"dev": "next dev"}` line added to your package.json.

Hope it helps